# I m working first time on pagination an gtting the error

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'sails.io']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

I'm getting an error like this

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider <- startFromFilter

Please help.

Comment: are you getting error while accessing filter in controller?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to import the filter into your controller/service etc.
instead import $filter and use it this way: `$filter("startFrom")(input,start);`